# Entity Framework Code-First Migrations renaming all tables to pluralized form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In the database I have inherited, the tables are named singularly (i.e. "dbo.Genre"). My mapping code sets the table to be singular as well:

```
public class GenreMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Genre>
{
    public GenreMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Genre");
    }
}
```

However, when I run Add-Migration, the resulting Up() function says...

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.Genre", newName: "Genres");
```

This occurs on all tables, and all of them have the ToTable mapping for singular.

I added the following snippet to the OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) function:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

However, it is still not working as expected. Is there anything else that could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove pluralization of table name it is correct.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

If you need pluralization of table just comment the above line of code.

Comment: I have added this, but it does not resolve the issue. Sorry I was not more clear on that.